# Starting Android emulator failed: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

Tags: android

I would like to do some debugging(Android native program without GUI) on a remote server which doesn't have display.

The command is:

```
./emulator -writable-system -avd Pixel_XL_API_25 -no-snapshot-load -qemu -no-skin -no-audio -no-window  -v
```

Error msg:

```
emulator: WARNING: System image is writable
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Aborted
```

I have the `-no-window` option why it still tried to connect to display?
I searched through Internet. It looks like it's a QT bug. Any idea to walk around it?

I tried to set the DISPLAY env var by `export DISPLAY=:0`. It doesn't work out.

Comment: were you able to find a solution ? having the same problem

Answer (score 2):

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Works for me on `Ubuntu 18.04`
Removing android studio and reinstall from Ubuntu Software Store also resolved for me.